# Linq Query toList() is empty but foreach works

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query:

```
IEnumerable<Network> net = from file in Directory.GetFiles(folder+ @"\network")
                           from lines in File.ReadLines(file).Skip(1)
                           let row = lines.Split(',')           
                           select new Network
                           {
                               networkname = getnetwork(row),
                               ...
                               networkdate = getnetworkdate(row)
                           };
```

when I use toList() on it, the list is empty but when I use a foreach loop where I use an empty List and add each item, it is not. Did I made a mistake in this query or could there be different source for this strange behavior?

UPDATE:
I am using it in a extension method like this:
This does not work:

```
public static void FillFromCsv(this List<Network> network)
    {
       [QUERY HERE]

       network = net.toList();
    }
```

This works:

```
public static void FillFromCsv(this List<Network> network)
    {
       [QUERY HERE]

       network.Clear();
       Foreach (Network n in net)
       {
            network.add(n);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you use `ToList` and `ForEach`?  Does it matter what order you do them in?

Comment: This might be caused by Linq deferred execution, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where is the file extension for @"\network" ?

Comment: It appears you're trying to parse .CSV files using C#. Would you like to [use a library](http://www.filehelpers.net/)?

Comment: Have you tried to create your own list by looping over the items adding each item to the list?
    var netList = new List<Network>();    
    foreach(var n in net) netList.Add(n);

Comment: Any chance its finding files it cant split or lines it cant split?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added an update to my description. The CSV import works just fine and with linq it is easy enough. So that I don't need a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `foreach` vs `ToList`.  The problem is that in the first method, you are not changing the list that's passed in.  You're overwriting the *local* reference with a *new* reference:

```
public static void FillFromCsv(this List<Network> network)
{
   [QUERY HERE]

   // this only affects the _local_ "network" reference, not the reference passed in
   network = net.toList();  
}
```

You *could* change the parameter to a `ref` parameter, but why use an extension method at all?  Why have the caller pass in a list if you're just going to blow it away?  I would just do

```
public static IEnumerable<Network> FillFromCsv()
{
   [QUERY HERE]

   return net.ToList();  
}
```

In the second method, you're clearing the list instance that's passed in and adding the results to it.  Which is fine, but it's *different* that what you're doing in the first method.

You *could* avoid the foreach by just doing:

```
public static void FillFromCsv(this List<Network> network)
{
   [QUERY HERE]

   network.Clear();
   network.AddRange(net);

}
```

But it seems odd to have the caller pass you a list and you clear it out and refill it.  A better method would be to just *return* a list (like the fist suggestion).

Comment: Thanks for your help D Stanley. I am using extensions because I have an extra static class for dealing with csv files as input. I like it when methods with nearly the same functionality "stick together". That is no real rational reason,I just find it more clearely arrange when same functionality is grouped togehter. So I would likely stay with that. On the other hand, maybe I should use a better approach as you mentioned. I will drink a beer over that. Thanks a lot :-)